# How to verify which node is master with kubernetes API python

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm currently using Kubernetes Python Client V1 API.
Since there is a way to list node details but I could not find which one is master

```py
k8s_api = client.CoreV1Api()
logger.info("Getting k8s nodes...")
response = k8s_api.list_node()
```

Comment: Eh, you deleted your last question in the middle of me writing a second comment to it, so I'll leave here (flag as no longer needed once see it). Your naming of label and it's values are questionable at best. Consider using `status="finished"` and alike. Also, consider dropping `_count` label. It can be easily calculated with something like `sum without (status)(my_metric)`. It only takes up space from Prometheus' storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k8s_api = client.CoreV1Api()
response = k8s_api.list_node()

# Loop through the nodes and check for the master node label
for node in response.items:
    if "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" in node.metadata.labels:
        print(f"Master node: {node.metadata.name}")
```